# PHPmailer email sent but not received at user end

Tags: html, css, phpmailer

I've been trying some of the solutions here but I am not able to figure out what the problem is. I am sending an SMTP mail using PHPmailer and in that mail I am using a values from users and some calculated at the backend. Please can someone help with this.

Before I put the text-to-image code in the PHPmailer was working.

Code was tested live/online server. I have checked the junk folder and I haven't received anything.

```
<?php
echo '
<html>
<head>
<title>Thank you for Registering</title>
<style type="text/css">
body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    background-image:url(images/bkgrd01.jpg);
    background-repeat:no-repeat;
}
.thankyoucontent {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 500px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-left: auto;
    text-align: center;
    border: 1px solid #999;
    -moz-border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 10px;
    -khtml-border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 10pt;
    background-color:#FFF;
}
.thankyoucontent p {
    font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-size: 12pt;    
    text-align:left;
}
@font-face {
    font-family: bcodefont;
    src: url(fonts/IDAutomationHC39M.ttf);
}
.thankyoucontent p.barcode {
    font-family: bcodefont;
    font-size: 18pt;
    font-style: normal;
    text-align:center;
}
</style>
</head>
<body> 
<div class="thankyoucontent">' ?>


<?php
$con = mysql_connect("localhost","username","password");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("dbname", $con);





/* ------------- GENERATING THE BARCODE -------------- */
    $result = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM wp_tps_forms");
    $rows = mysql_num_rows($result);

    global $bcode_user;

    $bcode_user = 600201700000 + $rows + 1;

    $flagemail = 0;

    while($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)){

        $Email=$row['email'];
        if(strcmp($Email, $_POST['Email']) == 0) { 
            exit("<p>This email is taken. Please use another to register.</p>");
        }

    }

/* ------------- SAVING DATA INTO DB -------------- */  
$sql="INSERT INTO wp_tps_forms (name, email, contact, barcode)
VALUES ('$_POST[Fname]','$_POST[Email]','$_POST[Tel]','$bcode_user')";

if (!mysql_query($sql,$con))
  {
  die('Error: ' . mysql_error()); exit('Error: ' . mysql_error());
  } 


/* --------------------> CONVERT TEXT TO IMAGE >------------------------ */

function ImageTTFCenter($image, $text, $font, $size, $angle = 45) 
{
    $xi = imagesx($image);
    $yi = imagesy($image);

    $box = imagettfbbox($size, $angle, $font, $text);

    $xr = abs(max($box[2], $box[4]));
    $yr = abs(max($box[5], $box[7]));

    $x = intval(($xi - $xr) / 2) - 20;
    $y = intval(($yi + $yr) / 2);

    return array($x, $y);
}

$im = @imagecreatefromjpeg('images/testimg(w).jpg');

// Create some colors
$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$black = imagecolorallocate($im, 0, 0, 0);

// The text to draw
$fbid ="$bcode_user"; 
$text ="$bcode_user";

$uploads_dir = 'images/';
// Replace path by your own font path
$font = './fonts/IDAutomationHC39M.ttf';

//image file name
$name = $uploads_dir.$fbid.".png"; 

list($x, $y) = ImageTTFCenter($im, $text, $font,16);

// Add the text
imagettftext($im, 16, 0, $x, $y, $black, $font, $text);

// Using imagepng() results in clearer text compared with imagejpeg()
imagepng($im,$name,9);
imagedestroy($im);

/* ---------------------------<<------------------------------- */







/* ---------------------- SEND EMAIL ----------------------- */

//Img path to be attached
$imgpath = 'images/' . $bcode_user . '.png';
/**

date_default_timezone_set('Etc/UTC');

require 'phpmailer/PHPMailerAutoload.php';

$mail = new PHPMailer;

$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;

$mail->Debugoutput = 'html';

$mail->Host = gethostbyname('smtp.gmail.com');
// if your network does not support SMTP over IPv6

$mail->Port = 587;

//Set the encryption system to use - ssl (deprecated) or tls
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';

//Whether to use SMTP authentication
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;

//Username to use for SMTP authentication - use full email address for gmail
$mail->Username = username@gmail.com";

//Password to use for SMTP authentication
$mail->Password = "password";

//Set who the message is to be sent from
$mail->setFrom('dummy@gmail.com', 'T2I - First Last');

//Set an alternative reply-to address
$mail->addReplyTo('dummy@gmail.com', 'Reply Email');


//Set who the message is to be sent to
$mail->addAddress($_POST['Email'], 'John Doe');

//Set the subject line
$mail->Subject = 'PHPMailer - Txt2Img Test Email';

$mail->AddEmbeddedImage($imgpath, 'bcodeimg');

$mail->AddEmbeddedImage('./images/testimg.jpg', 'bcodeimg', 'testimg.jpg'); 

$mail->AltBody = 'This is a plain-text message body';

$mail->Body = '<p>This is a test picture: <img src="cid:bcodeimg" /></p><p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; text-align:left;">Test 3 - (In Email Body)Thank you for registering. You will receive an email (Inbox/Junk folder) with a copy of your unique barcode. Alternatively, you can take a screenshot of the barcode and carry it with you to enter at the gates.</p>';

//send the message, check for errors
if (!$mail->send()) {
    echo "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
} else {
    echo '<p style="font-family: bcodefont; font-size: 18pt; font-style: normal; text-align:center;">' . $bcode_user . '</p><p style="font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; font-size: 12pt; text-align:left;">(WebPage Confirmation)Thank you for registering. You will receive an email(Inbox/Junk folder) with a copy of your unique barcode. Alternatively, you can take a screenshot of the barcode and carry it with you to enter at the gates.</p>';
}



?>





<?php 
echo '</div></body></html>';
?>
```

Comment: That was my last try before posting here. I even copy pasted the gmail.phps file in the examples and it didn't work.

Comment: This was a server problem. It had worked the previous day. Sorry for this post. I have moved to a better server.